# Troubles with pascal conditions

Tags: pascal, freepascal, turbo-pascal

I'm writing the program with Pascal. And have some troubles with conditions.

For example, if you write in input 
1 1 
1 4 
5 1 
2 2

`tArea1` = 6 and `sumAreas` = 6 too 
But in "if" structure this doesn't working correctly.

Help me, please. Tnx.

```
var
  x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4: real;
  line1Length, line2Length, line3Length : real; // Length of the triangle area
  tArea1, tArea2, tArea3, tArea4, sumAreas : real;

  function segmentLength (x,y,x0,y0:real);
  begin
    segmentLength := sqrt(sqr(x-x0) + sqr(y-y0));
  end;

  function triangleArea (a,b,c:real);
  var
    p: real; // Half of the perimetr
  begin
    p := (a+b+c)/2;
    triangleArea := sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
  end;

begin
  writeln('write x1,y1');
  readln(x1,y1);
  writeln('write x2,y2');
  readln(x2,y2);
  writeln('write x3,y3');
  readln(x3,y3);
  writeln('write x4,y4');
  readln(x4,y4);

  // First triangle
  line1Length := segmentLength(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  line2Length := segmentLength(x2,y2,x3,y3);
  line3Length := segmentLength(x3,y3,x1,y1);

  tArea1 := triangleArea(line1Length, line2Length, line3Length);

  // Second triangle
  line1Length := segmentLength(x4,y4,x2,y2);
  line2Length := segmentLength(x2,y2,x3,y3);
  line3Length := segmentLength(x3,y3,x4,y4);

  tArea2 := triangleArea(line1Length, line2Length, line3Length);

  // Third triangle

  line1Length := segmentLength(x4,y4,x1,y1);
  line2Length := segmentLength(x1,y1,x3,y3);
  line3Length := segmentLength(x3,y3,x4,y4);

  tArea3 := triangleArea(line1Length, line2Length, line3Length);

  // Fourth Triangle

  line1Length := segmentLength(x4,y4,x1,y1);
  line2Length := segmentLength(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  line3Length := segmentLength(x2,y2,x4,y4);

  tArea4 := triangleArea(line1Length, line2Length, line3Length);

  // Check dot situated

  sumAreas := tArea4+tArea2+tArea3;

  writeln(tArea1, ' // ', sumAreas); //

  if (sumAreas = tArea1) then
  begin
    writeln('In');
  end
  else
  begin
    writeln('Out');
  end;

end.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what problem are you running into? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lazy student's homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way floating point numbers are represented by the computer there can be inconsistencies when comparing two numbers that appear to be identical. Unlike integers, IEEE floating point numbers are only approximates, not exact numbers. The need to convert the numbers to a form the computer can store in binary leads to minor precision or round-off deviations. For example `1.3` may really be represented as `1.29999999999`.

Therefore you should never use `=` or `<>` to compare two floating point numbers. Instead, subtract the two numbers and compare them against a very small number.

For you case try to use:

```
 if abs(sumAreas - tArea1) < 0.00001 then
```

There may particularly be problems when using conversion functions such as `StrToFloat`, `TextToFloat` and `StrToCurr`

```
 if FloatToStr(sumAreas) = FloatToStr(tArea1) then
```

Also it, but not recommended:

```
if Round(sumAreas) = Round(tArea1) then
```

Reference: 
[Problems comparing floating point numbers.](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/22507)

Comment: Your IF's have redundant braces.:-)

Comment: Yes.  if x>4 then is perfectly fine

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Ok, thanks. I've already modified it. It's just a habit from C # :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing floating point values with the equality (**=**) operator. When comparing floating point values, a very small difference in value (because of numeric reasons) can cause deviations, causing the comparison to fail.

A better equality test is

```
 if abs(value-valuetocompareto)<eps then
   writeln('bingo') 
 else
   writeln('tryagain');
```

with eps an appropriate tolerance for how much a value is allowed to deviate. (try 0.0001 to start with)

If it is a homework assignment, add the motivation for the size of EPS based on logic or numeric math in a comment.